# Mutual exclusive events are dependent

Tags: probability

> Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, $P(A \text{ and }B)=0$, then $A$
>   and $B$ are dependent.

So I know that $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A \cap B)= P(A) P(B)$
How do I use that piece of information to prove the statement?

Comment: Do you know anything else about the probability space? In particular, is it possible that $P(C)=0$ for some $C\ne\emptyset$?

Answer (score 0):

> > So I know that A and B are independent if P(A intersect B)= P(A)*P(B) How do i use that piece of information to prove the statement?

The contrapositive of that is:

> If $P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)~P(B)$, then $A$ and $B$ are *not* independent.

So... next we(you) need to consider that *if* $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=0,$ then

1. *when* is $0\neq \mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B)$ and
2. *when* is $0=\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B)$

...

Comment: Nothing can be concluded from this if $A$ and $B$ both have probability $0.$ More information is needed.

Comment: @Cameron Yes, we *do* indeed need to consider that if $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=0,$ then (1) *when* is $0\neq \mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B)$ and (2) *when* is $0=\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B)$